# Are AWS Security Group Port Ranges Inclusive or Exclusive

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

AWS security groups allow a port range to be specified for permitted traffic, written in the form `1234-5678`: would that be inclusive of ports `1234` and `5678`, or exclusive of either/both of those ports?

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule) doesn't seem to describe this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since example shows `0 - 65535` and 2^16 is `65536` (otherwise it would be `-1 - 65536`), than it means inclusively.

Comment: Thanks! What confused me is that I didn't think 0 was a valid port though?

Comment: @James Seems like port can be **0**. https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&client=firefox-b-ab&q=can+port+number+be+0&oq=can+port+n&gs_l=serp.3.0.0l3j0i22i30k1.6098.8433.0.10467.10.10.0.0.0.0.176.1157.5j5.10.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.10.1121...0i131k1j0i67k1.V6pR-IXkxFY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&bvm=bv.137904068,d.bGg&biw=1920&bih=957&ech=1&psi=ssohWNeKGYKRsAHjj4AQ.1478609586127.3&ei=ssohWNeKGYKRsAHjj4AQ&emsg=NCSR&noj=1&gfe_rd=cr